# How can I download using accelerators?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Can anyone tell me how can I use internet download manager downloading movies on Tor browser please?  I mean; when you use Tor Browser and need to download a movie file using Internet Download Manager or Flashget as a download accelerators,it must stars downloading ,Right? But it doesn't start downloading from Tor Browser on my PC!! How can I set Tor Browser as a default browser on my IDM accelerator on my PC??
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Please do *not* download big movie files over Tor. It will slowdown the tor network for other people. And you will not get maximum speed of download in Tor, get a VPN for fast download speeds (..and to not harm Tor network)

Answer (score 1):

Using Download accelerators **will harm your anonymity**. But if you must use one then you can use "[Down Them all](http://downthemall.net/)" which is a Firefox add-on and will download all files over Tor.